# Using OTG cable, transfer file from cardreader to external harddisk, is it possible?

Tags: usb, usb-host-mode, usb-on-the-go

I will be going on a holiday and I want to be able to back up my photos to my external harddrive.

Usually this means bringing a laptop with me.

However I have :

- Galaxy Nexus, rooted and unlocked
- OTG Cable
- Powered USB hub
- Standard, fullsize SD card reader

So I hooked up everything. Nexus-> OTG -> USB Hubs with power supply -> External Harddrive and SD card reader

Nothing happens.

I can connect a Logitech wireless mouse to it and I can use my phone via the mouse. So everything are connected, with power.

I read that I need to mount the external drive and the SD card reader. So I opened Astro but it doesn't seem to auto mount.

I searched and I found StickMount, an App which mount USB storage devices for you. I tried that however it will not mount my external drive nor my SD card reader.

Can anyone help please?

EDIT: I downloaded a Root Checker and found out that my device is not properly rooted, perhaps that is why StickMount could not mount my drives. Does anyone know how would I mount the drives without root access? Is it possible?